# OpenOffice Calc can not read a simple CSV file. Why?

Tags: csv, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a Web site (PHP) that generates a CSV file (text/csv) with the following content:

```
ID;E-Mail_User;Name;Applikation;Rolle;Auftragsdatum;Administrator
522;user@domain;WXDUILAS;ABCD;XYZ;2009-03-04 05:00:09;user@domain
```

When I select OpenOffice to show the CSV file only an empty spread sheet is shown. No error is displayed. When I try to open the file with `oocalc test.csv` the same happens. I have tried different versions of OpenOffice.

What is wrong with the file? How can I get an error message out of OpenOffice?

**Update:**
It does not have anything to do with the use of semicolons. I have reduced the file to 4 charaters. A file with the contents `ID;A` opens the CSV import dialog. But a `ID;E` opens an empty sheet. Why?

**Update 2:**
The pattern `id;E` also works. `ID;E` must be some kind of magic code. Does anybody know the meaning?

Comment: It DOES have to do with the semicolons - a file containing only ID,E causes the import dialog to open. As Matt said, CSV is comma-separated, whether you like it or no.

Comment: The question is why `ID;A` works and `ID;E` does not.

Comment: Bug in ooffice? Whatever, the answer is to generate proper CSV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ID; in the first 3 characters of a file is the signature for a SYLK file. The fourth character can be a P, N or an E which flags certain information about how the rest of the file should be processed... so your "CSV" file is almost certainly being parsed as a SYLK file when that initial signature is read, and the remainder of the file is not valid SYLK format.

Comment: Excel exhibits the same behavior. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323626/-sylk-file-format-is-not-valid-error-message-when-you-open-file - "A SYLK file is a text file that begins with "ID" or "ID_xxxx", where xxxx is a text string. The first record of a SYLK file is the ID_Number record. When Excel identifies this text at the beginning of a text file, it interprets the file as a SYLK file." - Even chnaging the first column header to `id` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) means **C** omma **S** eparated **V** alues, which is not what your document contains.

Those are semicolons.

If possible, change the PHP code to generate this instead (which *is* actually CSV):

```
ID,E-Mail_User,Name,Applikation,Rolle,Auftragsdatum,Administrator
522,user@domain,WXDUILAS,ABCD,XYZ,2009-03-04 05:00:09,user@domain
```

...or specify `;` as the delimiter using the `Text Import` dialog.

Comment: it does not seem to be possible, if the browser starts oocalc.

Comment: If you don't tell the program that the delimiter is `;` rather than `,` it's not going to magically know that.

Answer (score 0):

Add space after ID (i.e. "ID ").

Not the perfect solution but worked for me.