# Exporting a .CSV file, if I export it with column names it tells my it is an SYLK format

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel, csv

Exporting contents from an SQL Database table to a .csv file. If I add in the column names it gives me these errors when trying to open the downloaded .csv file:

[image: Error #1]

[image: Error #2]

However, if I export it without the columns it will open up just fine without errors. I've tried changing the Content-Type: from text/csv to application/csv, didn't change anything. I'm out of ideas.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=applications.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

ini_set('display_errors',1);
$private=1;
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("cif") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM applications";
$select_c = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

/* The line below is what I comment out to remove the column names */
$result.="ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,ORGANIZATION,TITLE\n"; 
/* The line above is what I comment out to remove the column names */

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_c, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $result.="{$row['ID']},";
    $result.="{$row['LAST_NAME']},";
    $result.="{$row['FIRST_NAME']},";
    $result.="{$row['ORGANIZATION']},";
    $result.="{$row['TITLE']},";
    $result.="\n";

}
    echo $result; 
?>
```

Comment: look at the content of the file in a text editor rater than excel.

Comment: @JamesBirkett Unfortunately viewing it in Excel is a necessity

Comment: Post the shortest version of the csv file that still exhibits the error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032049/openoffice-calc-can-not-read-a-simple-csv-file-why/6244279#6244279

Comment: Wrap your `ID` text in quotes: that way, it doesn't exhibit a SYLK file signature, and the quotes won't affect the value when it is imported as a CSV

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker, worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a number of columns mismatch.

The header row has 5 entries, but each subsequent row has 6 (because of the trailing comma).

You can either add a comma to the end of your header row or remove the trailing comma from the data rows.

---

**EDIT:** SYLK files start with "ID".  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626

Make your first column name not start with "ID" and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Just tried it both ways (adding a comma, or removing it from the data) and I still get the error

Comment: In my case, the first column name "ID" was the culprit; I've just renamed it with "PID". Though someone can just add a space with it like "ID " to fix the issue :)